# How to prevent the TextView from being cutoff by the parent container?

Tags: android, textview, mpandroidchart

I'm using [*mpandroidchart*](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) to generate a chart on one-third of my device screen. As I move towards the edge of the screen the TextView gets cutoff by the padding on the sides on the parent container. Is there a way to fix it without changing my UI?

Towards the edge: *(gets cutoff)*

[image]

---

Away from the edge: *(appears good)*

[image]

---

marker_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/my_marker">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewMarker"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check if there is padding in parent layout

Comment: Apply   android:layout_centerInParent="true" to your TextView in order to make the text appear in center of your relativelayout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply the

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

on your TextView's parent.

Comment: regarding of the layout, you may need to add it to more views, but this indeed the right solution.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried `gravity` attribute?

Try this method to make the text align center.

```
android:gravity="center"
```

make sure that, use `android:gravity` , dont use `android:layout_gravity`.